# How to make an image fit only 50% of the screen in NextJS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass, next.js

I'm trying to make a image fit only 50% of the screen in NextJS. NextJS provides an Image component that we have to use and not the image element. That Image component already has its own inline styling for the image element and wraps it in a styled span element.
Currently I wrap that Image component in a span tag so I can style it but I'm finding it difficult to make it fit only 50% of the screen.

Code:

```js
<div className='pagewrapper'>
  <section className='authpages_section'>
    <span className='authpages_heroimg'>
      <Image src='/assets/hero.png' alt='an hero img' />
    </span>
  </section>
  <section className='authpages_section'>
   <Logo />
   <div>{children}</div>
  </section>
</div>

styling:
.pagewrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;

  .authpages {
     &_section {
       flex-basis: 50%;
       height: 100vh;
     }

     &_heroimg {
       display: inline-flex;
     }
   }
}
```

Here's a visual representation:

[visual representation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vfp4i.png)

Comment: I've been thinking of using `background-image` to solve this but the problem is I'll be using this component to display different images for different page (passing the image url as a prop) and I'll also love to take advantage of NextJS image optimization.

Comment: give the image itself 100% width so it fills the container, then work from there. `.authpages_heroimg > img { width: 100%}`. Not sure if that fixes the issue or not as it isn't quite clear what problem you have from the provided image (or if that is what you want it to look like), but my guess is that the img was not filling the space correctly looking at the CSS without a fiddle to play with. If you want to put a fiddle / codepen / stackblitz etc. together or give a little more detail as to what issue you are having I can help further!

Comment: @GrahamRitchie Hi! thanks for taking the time out to help me with this problem, I appreciate!
I tried stackblitz but it's having a problem using remote images with the NextJS demo & fiddle, codepen don't work well with the demo. So here's a Github repo that reproduces the problem: https://github.com/danBamikiya/nextjs-image-styling-issue

Answer (score 0):

Can you do it like this:

1. For the `.authpages_section` set `width: 50%`
2. For the Image element - add some class and set its styles to `max-width: 100%`

**Update**
To achieve what you need, remove the `layout="fill"` property,
so your component will actually look like this:

```
 <Image
   src={HeroImg}
   alt="an hero img"
 />
```

Comment: Thanks! That doesn't work as NextJS already adds `max-width: 100%` inline styling to the element. Here's a Github repo that reproduces the problem if you want to help further: https://github.com/danBamikiya/nextjs-image-styling-issue Thanks a lot!